# Is there some way to find out the senate or house candidates endorsed by Bernie Sanders?

Tags: united-states, congress, endorsement

Wikipedia lists endorsements in each race, e.g.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_House_of_Representatives_elections_in_Texas#District_25. Some tweets by candidates also announce endorsement.  Is there some way to find out as many as possible people who run for senator or house representative and have received endorsement from a politician?

I am mainly/only interested in who Bernie Sanders has endorsed, and I am satisfied with  those listed in Wikipedia, and only if Wikipedia could be queried ...

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, Wikidata doesn't seem to have this data.

Answer (score 2):

There is no comprehensive database of endorsements. Candidates or third-parties may compile lists, but no one is required to do so. Some third-parties like newspapers and Ballotpedia do their best to maintain lists, but there isn't any central repository for this kind of information.

The definition of an endorsement is itself slippery.

For example, the New England Journal of Medicine recently urged its readers not to vote for President Trump but didn't expressly endorse his opponent.

Similarly, many primary candidates, during the primary said that they would support the winner of the primary in the general election. But that doesn't mean that when the nominee was chosen that the primary candidates actually did anything affirmative to state that they endorsed the winner. Is that an endorsement? It is hard to say.

Comment: I am mainly interested in who Bernie has endorsed, and I am satisfied with all those listed in Wikipedia, and only if Wikipedia could be queried ...